# Retrieve Logged in user information or entity in mvc 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a better way to store the logged in user's information or entity in an mvc 3 application without using a session? Because before, I would like to store it in a session. But since there is no concept of Session, what would be the best way to retrieve it?

Here is the sample entity class of the user:

```
public class User
{
  public UserName { get; set; }
  public Password { get; set; }
  public SecurityGroup { get; set; }
  public DepartmentID { get; set; }
}
```

There will be some pages which I would need the `SecurityGroup` of the user and there will be some pages that I would need the `DepartmentID`. It will be foolish if I would retrieve the data every time I need it.

Just need your opinion guys because I'm still starting with this technology.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But since there is no concept of Session, what would be the best way to retrieve it?

I don't understand this. Of course there is a concept of Session in MVC3. I think it depends on what you want to do, and there are several questions you need to ask yourself:

1. Will closing the tab log out my user automatically?
2. When WILL the session ends? (e.g. pressing 'logout', a timeout)

The way I find it most useful is leveraging the ASP.NET FormsAuthentication mechanism and session vars.

Here's an example from a code I've written:

```
var curUser = context.Session["User"] as ViewUser;

if (curUser == null)
{
   // Generate token from given FB access token
   var token= 'your token';

   // Set the forms authentication auth cookie
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(token, false);

   // Get user details to put inside the session vars
   var UserInstance = getUser(token);

   // Put user details in session vars
   context.Session["User"] = UserInstance;
}
```

token is for oAuth and such, that's how that system was built, you can put the id of the user instead.

Now this leverages the FormsAuthintication since you also have a secured cookie which lasts through the session and you don't need to address the database each time with the token, since I put the user model inside a Session var.

This allows to do a fallback, meaning that:

1. Try to parse the session var, if not
2. Check if the user is logged in, and parse the user again from database
3. If user not logged in - implement your logic.

This worked out nice for me.
Hope it helps.

Comment: So you're saying that even in MVC 3, you can use Session to store the logged in user's entity like `Session["loggedUser"] = user;`?

Comment: Yes, of course you can (I use it). This (the answer) is also how you can make it persistent with your database.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a BaseController that your other controllers will inherit from and then check the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User in ExecuteCore() and save the SecurityGroup in ViewData.

```
ViewData("SecurityGroup") = User.SecurityGroup
```

Then you can access it in any controller.

Example (forgive the VB.NET)

```
Public Class BaseController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Protected Overrides Sub ExecuteCore()

        Dim currentUser As User = MyDatabaseLayer.GetUserByEmail(User.Identity.Name)

        ViewData("SecurityGroup") = currentUser.SecurityGroup

        MyBase.ExecuteCore()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Then in one of your standard controllers

```
Public Class MyController
    Inherits BaseController

    Public Function Index()

        If ViewData("SecurityGroup") = something Then

             'do something

        End If

    End Function

 End Class
```

Comment: Interesting! Do you have any examples for this? Because right now, I have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

> It will be foolish if I would retrieve the data every time I need it.

I don't think so, its how it should be done. If you are thinking about storing these values in Session, then you must also have to device a way to kill session when user closes the app (Here 'closes' does not mean he logs out, he may have simply closed the tab/browser)

What you can you is `user.identity.name` to get the username of the current logged in user and fetch the `SecurityGroup/DepartmentId` whenever wherever you need it.